# Given a Geodesic square what is the area of the square?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I need help with this question

Given a Geodesic square on unit ball, The interiors angle are 2 radians each,
What is the area of the square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a geodesic polygon on a ball with radius $r$, the area is $(2\pi - \sum_k {\alpha}_k)r^2$ where $\alpha_k$ is the $k^{th}$ signed exterior angle.
If one walks around the curve bounding the polygon in counterclockwise manner. If at $k^{th}$ corner the curve turns to the left, $\alpha_k$ will be positive. if the curve turns to the right, $\alpha_k$ will be negative.

This is a special case of [Gauss Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem). see wiki entry for more info.

For the polygon at hand, all $\alpha_k = \pi - 2$ with $r = 1$. This means the area of the geodesic square is

$$2\pi - 4(\pi - 2) = 8-2\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

Divide the square into two triangles by its diagonal.

Now use the formula for area of geodesic triangle where $A, B, C$ are angles of triangle $$\text{area} = r^2( A+B+C -\pi)$$

Summing up ($r=1$), $$\text{area of square} = 2+2+2+2-\pi-\pi=8-2\pi$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more for me?

Comment: Do you know how to find area of a geodesic triangle, given its angles? Then you can triangulate the square and sum up the areas.

Comment: I don't know hot to find ared of a geodesic triangle :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\text{Area (n-gon)}=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i - (n-2)\pi = 2\pi - \sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i - \pi)$$

In the case of a triangle, for example, the area will be the difference between the sum of the angles and $pi.$ In the question it is $8-2\pi.$

This follows from the [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Statement):

$$\int_T K \text{d}A + \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{E_i} k_g \text ds + \sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_{\text{ext}_i}= 2 \pi \chi (T)\tag 1$$

where $T$ is the spherical triangle; $K$ is the Gaussian curvature; $E_i$ are the three edges of the triangle; $k_g$ is the geodesic curvature of the edges; $\alpha_{\text{ext}_i}$ the exterior angles, which are related to the interior angles by $ \alpha_{\text{ext}_i}= \pi-\alpha_i.$

Since $\int_{E_i} k_g \text ds=0$ because the triangle is bounded by geodesics (zero curvature); and $\chi (T)=1,$ because the spherical triangle is topologically a disc, equation $(1)$ becomes

$$\int_T K \text{d}A +  \sum_{i=1}^3 \pi - \alpha_i= 2 \pi $$

Since the curvature of the sphere is constant, and $K=\frac 1 {r^2},$

$$\begin{align}
A &=\frac 1 K \left( \sum_{i=1}^3  \alpha_i - \pi \right)\\
A &= r^2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^3  \alpha_i - \pi \right)\\
A &=  \sum_{i=1}^3  \alpha_i - \pi 
\end{align}$$

when $r=1.$

The general formula for $n$-gons can be deduced inductively by splitting $n$-gons into spherical triangles.